# How to access array element inside 'field' attribute of PrimeNG autoComplete

Tags: angular, typescript, autocomplete, primeng

I have a list of JSON object, 1 of the sample is below

```
 [
  {
    id: 'cont-609',
    contactMedium: [
      {
        characteristic: {
          emailAddress: 'test@gmail.com'
        }
      }
    ]
  }]
```

My goal here is to access emailAddress (**contactMedium[0].characteristic.emailAddress**) inside PrimeNG autoComplete attribute 'field' so that I can display list of emails in drop down.

**There will be always 1 element inside contactMedium**

Below is my typescript code

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuItem } from 'primeng/api';
import { SelectItem } from 'primeng/api';
import { SelectItemGroup } from 'primeng/api';
import { FilterService } from 'primeng/api';
import { AutoComplete } from 'primeng/autocomplete';
import { CountryService } from './countryservice';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  providers: [CountryService, FilterService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  userDetails: any[];

  selectedUserDetails: any[];

  selectedValue: any;

  selectedUserDetail: any;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userDetails = [
      {
        id: 'cont-609',
        contactMedium: [
          {
            characteristic: {
              emailAddress: 'test@gmail.com'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 'cont-610',
        contactMedium: [
          {
            characteristic: {
              emailAddress: 'test@gmail.com'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 'cont-611',
        contactMedium: [
          {
            characteristic: {
              emailAddress: 'test@gmail.com'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 'cont-612',
        contactMedium: [
          {
            characteristic: {
              emailAddress: 'test@gmail.com'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 'cont-614',
        contactMedium: [
          {
            characteristic: {
              emailAddress: 'test@gmail.com'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
  }

  filterUserDetails(event) {
    let filtered: any[] = [];

    for (let val of this.userDetails) {
      filtered.push(val);
    }
    this.selectedUserDetails = filtered;
  }

  getUserDetails(): Promise<any[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(this.userDetails);
  }

  chooseItem(event) {
    this.selectedUserDetail =
      event.contactMedium[0].characteristic.emailAddress;
  }
}
```

Below is my HTML code

```html
        <h5>Dropdown Testing</h5>
    <p>selectedUserDetail : {{selectedUserDetail}}</p>
    <p>TestVal : {{testVal}}</p>
    <p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="selectedUserDetail" [suggestions]="selectedUserDetails"
      (completeMethod)="filterUserDetails($event)" [dropdown]="true" field="contactMedium">
      <!--<ng-template let-userDetails pTemplate=" item">
        <div>{{userDetails.contactMedium[0].characteristic.emailAddress}}</div>
      </ng-template> -->
    </p-autoComplete>
```

This part of the attribute is not working, **field="contactMedium[0].characteristic.emailAddress"**
but if I place "id" from the json which is not array it works **field="id"** , but the goal here is to display emails.

Below is the link of the code if you want to access for experiment :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-autocomplete-demo-dyihrs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

It's not possible, because primeng doesn't accept fields as part of an array. You can check code here in the [autocomplete component](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/003d8eb55ffa4d121300d9b9875aa809b69ad1d3/src/app/components/autocomplete/autocomplete.ts#L782) and here, in the [function used to resolve field](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/003d8eb55ffa4d121300d9b9875aa809b69ad1d3/src/app/components/utils/objectutils.ts#L75)

**---**

Primeng doesn't catch the array inside contactMedium:

```
contactMedium[0].characteristic.emailAddress
```

I suppose that [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/autocomplete) refers to an Object without arrays.

> AutoComplete can also work with objects using the field property that defines the label to display as a suggestion.

As an alternative, you can manipulate the object to remove the array.

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-autocomplete-demo-9ivy5r?file=src/app/app.component.ts), you can confirm that using contactMedium as array, doesn't work.

Comment: Hello Georgeos,  Thank you for your suggestion, I tried the approach you suggested earlier but I was stuck at 1 point when I was creating custom JSON object where my key is configurable "contactMedium[0].characteristic.emailAddress"  and I was not able to get the value at run time, I asked suggestions in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67742949/how-to-access-json-object-value-with-dynamic-key-in-typescript-with-angular

Comment: Ok, I'll check yourt post. Just FYI check my edited answer.